# How to use an extension during the ongoing execution of a Selenium script?

Tags: java, python, selenium, automation, browser-extension

I'm running a Selenium script and adding an extension within it. The extension starts after the browser is invoked when I run the script. So, basically, my goal is to launch a Selenium script and populate some data with it. Once it is done, then I need the extension to take control and execute some work. And once the extension process is finished, the selenium script should reclaim control.

As a result, the project has been divided into three parts. The first section must run the script, in the second part extension should fill some data and, in the third portion control will be taken over by Selenium. Is that even possible? If that's the case, could you please share your thoughts?